# How to customize UICollectionView Cell items behavior?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm learning swift and iOS dev!

I decided to build a little app, with UICollectionView.

So my question is how do I customize the behavior of UICollectionView Cell.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

I have two array:

```
"temps": [
    "Présent",
    "Passé composé",
    "Imparfait",
    "Plus-que-parfait",
    "Passé simple",
    "Passé antérieur",
    "Futur",
    "Futur antérieur",
    "Futur proche",
    "Présent",
    "Passé",
    "Passé - forme alternative",
    "Présent",
    "Imparfait",
    "Plus-que-parfait",
    "Passé",
    "Présent",
    "Présent",
    "Passé"
],
```

And `"list": [
        "je suis",
        "tu es",
        "il est",
        "nous sommes",
        "vous êtes",
        "ils sont",
        "j'ai été",
        "tu as été",
        "il a été",
        "nous avons été",
        "vous avez été",
        "ils ont été",
        "j'étais",....]`etc....

The temps array is rendering just as expected but the list does not.

instead I get this:

[image]

Here is my UICollectionView methods:

```
 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var temps = [String]()

    if let temp = verb {
        temps = temp.temps

    }
    return temps.count
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell:IndicatifCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "indicatif", for: indexPath) as! IndicatifCollectionViewCell

    cell.temp.text = verb?.temps[indexPath.row]

    cell.je.text = verb?.list[indexPath.row]
    cell.tu.text = verb?.list[indexPath.row]
    cell.il.text = verb?.list[indexPath.row]
    cell.nous.text = verb?.list[indexPath.row]
    cell.vous.text = verb?.list[indexPath.row]
    cell.ils.text = verb?.list[indexPath.row]




    return cell


}
```

Comment: The arrays are coming from (API).

Comment: 2 things load data to your collection view using temp array. And once temp array has required data reload collectionview.

Comment: Could you be more specific? where should I reload the CollectionView, it's already been loaded in data request method: DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            self.indicatifCollectionView.reloadData()
                            
                        }

Comment: Oh, If I am getting the problem right, I believe your data structure is more complex than I thought. It is more of an architectural decision. You should bind temps value to their associated list items. So both of these are in sync.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. a little bit explanation maybe!

Comment: So I am adding my suggestion as an answer, a comment box wouldn't take that big of a response. Which I will delete if it doesn't solve your problem, as I am still not 100% sure that I get the problem right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191985/discussion-between-rptwsthi-and-madeny).

Comment: @rptwsthi Ok, I'm goin to try that if it works I'll accept as answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong, the easy way to accomplish that was to use switch statement:

```
switch indexPath {

    case [0, 0]:

        cell.temp.text = temps[0]

        cell.je.text = lists[0]
        cell.tu.text = lists[1]
        cell.il.text = lists[2]
        cell.nous.text = lists[3]
        cell.vous.text = lists[4]
        cell.ils.text = lists[5]
    default:
        print("...")
    }
```

so on..

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to items of list alongside with items of temp array here: and these are your lsuta nd temp array:

```
"temps": [
          "Présent",
          "Passé composé",
          "Imparfait",
          "Plus-que-parfait",
          "Passé simple",
          "Passé antérieur",
          "Futur",
          "Futur antérieur",
          "Futur proche",
          "Présent",
          "Passé",
          "Passé - forme alternative",
          "Présent",
          "Imparfait",
          "Plus-que-parfait",
          "Passé",
          "Présent",
          "Présent",
          "Passé"
          ],
"list": [
             "je suis",
             "tu es",
             "il est",
             "nous sommes",
             "vous êtes",
             "ils sont",
             "j'ai été",
             "tu as été",
             "il a été",
             "nous avons été",
             "vous avez été",
             "ils ont été",
             "j'étais",....
         ]
```

You want these data to go alonside each other inside one cell. I would make structure something like:

```
"finalDictionary": {
    "Présent" : [
                 "je suis",
                 "tu es",
                 "il est",
                 "nous sommes",
                 "vous êtes",
                 "ils sont",
    ],
    "Passé composé" : [
                       "tu as été",
                       "il a été",
                       "nous avons été",
                       "vous avez été",
                       "ils ont été",
                       "j'étais"
    ]
    "Imparfait": [
                  "ils sont",
                  "j'ai été",
                  "tu as été",
                  "il a été",
                  "nous avons été",
    ]
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

Now of course in your `numberOfItemsInSection` you would like to return `finalDictionary.allkeys().count` and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you want to set values as:

```
if let key:String = finalDictionary()[indexPath.row] {
    cell.temp.text = key
    cell.je.text = finalDictionary[key][0]
    cell.tu.text = finalDictionary[key][1]
    cell.il.text = finalDictionary[key][2]
    cell.nous.text = finalDictionary[key][3]
    cell.vous.text = finalDictionary[key][4]
    cell.ils.text = finalDictionary[key][6]
}
```